# Doesn't the latest Admob for Android Studio need settings in the AndroidManifest any more?

Tags: android, android-studio, admob

I have noticed that [the latest official (English) Admob documentation for Android Studio](https://developers.google.com/admob/android/quick-start) doesn't mention about adding permissions and meta-data tag in the AndroidManifest.xml like the older documentation for Eclipse:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>

<application>
    <!--This meta-data tag is required to use Google Play Services.-->
    <meta-data android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
        android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />
```

According to the recent documentation for Android Studio, it looks like all we need to configure is to update dependency in the build.gradle:

```
dependencies {
    ...
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:8.4.0'
    ...
}
```

Does AndroidManifest need not be declared explicitly any more for Admob on Android Studio?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In a word, no. The gradle artifacts have their own manifests that will be merged into the final one for the application.

Comment: Actually I removed the two permissions from my AndroidManifest and uploaded the apk onto GooglePlay. Then the developer console says it has the two permissions. So, now I'm sure you're right. Thank you!

Comment: No problem. On the odd chance you'd like to know more about how the manifest merges work, there's a doc for it: http://developer.android.com/tools/building/manifest-merge.html